# In sympy plotting, how can I get a plot with a fixed aspect ratio?

Tags: python, plot, sympy

If I plot a circle with this snippet

```
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x y')        
p1 = plot_implicit(Eq(x**2 +y**2, 1),aspect_ratio=(1.,1.))
```

I will get a figure window like this one

[image]

Now the aspect ratio is not what I was expecting because I see an ellipse instead of a circle. Moreover, if I change the aspect ratio of the **window** (dragging the bottom-right corner of the window) I get also a change in the aspect ratio of the plot... The following image is what I get after dragging the corner in order to see a circle:

[image]

I would like to get a plot like the one you get in Matlab when you set `axis equal`, see http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/aspect-ratio-for-2-d-axes.html when you plot an ellipse

[image]

What am I missing?

I am using Jupyter and the version of the notebook server is 4.1.0 and is running on: Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]

Comment: I tried on `window2010` and `python 2.7.x` and `sympy 1.0`, same issue as yours. I am wondering if there is a `bug` either in `python 2.7` or  `sympy 1.0`. I dont have `python 3.x`, but it needs to be tried on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now in Sept 2019 this code works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy

x, y = sympy.symbols('x y')

plt.ion() #interactive on 

p1 = sympy.plot_implicit(sympy.Eq(x**2 +y**2, 4), block = False)

fg, ax = p1._backend.fig, p1._backend.ax  # get matplotib's figure and axes

# Use matplotlib to change appearance:
ax.axis('tight')  # list of float or {‘on’, ‘off’, ‘equal’, ‘tight’, ‘scaled’, ‘normal’, ‘auto’, ‘image’, ‘square’}
ax.set_aspect("equal") # 'auto', 'equal' or a positive integer is allowed
ax.grid(True)
plt.ioff() #interactive off
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: It doesn't work for me AttributeError: 'Plot' object has no attribute '_backend'

Comment: @GM, it doesn't work, except in Jupyter environment.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is covered in Sympy's stable API, but you can extract matplotlib's figure and axis instance and the use standard matplotlib calls to change the appearance of your plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sy

x, y = sy.symbols('x y')
p1 = sy.plot_implicit(sy.Eq(x**2 +y**2, 4))
fg, ax = p1._backend.fig, p1._backend.ax  # get matplotib's figure and ax

# Use matplotlib to change appearance: 
ax.axis('tight')  # list of float or {‘on’, ‘off’, ‘equal’, ‘tight’, ‘scaled’, ‘normal’, ‘auto’, ‘image’, ‘square’}
ax.set_aspect("equal") # 'auto', 'equal' or a positive integer is allowed
ax.grid(True)
fg.canvas.draw()


plt.show()  # enter matplotlib's event loop (not needed in Jupyter)
```

This gives:
[image: Tight Axis with equal aspect ratio]

Comment: May you please write the version of your Python environment? I tested your code and I get a plot different from the one you attached. Thank you.

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson I am using Debian/Sid with matplotlib 1.5, ipython 2.4, Sympy 0.7.6.1 and python 2.7/3.5. I reran it and got the desired results when using pylab (`%pylab` in the ipython shell or --pylab as parameter ) but not when not using it. I am a bit clueless concerning possible causes.

Comment: in Sympy 1.0 it does not work...
function show() in plot.py call self.plt.show() instead self.fig.show().

As fast workaround/test replacing plt to fig give expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Within the help for `plot_implicit`, the `x_var` and `y_var`-arguments are mentioned. Using them allows you to manually set limits to the x and y axis. If you scale those limits appropriately, you can achieve an even aspect ratio.

```
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols('x y')

scal = 3840/2400 # corresponds to your screen resolution
a = 1.05

p1 = plot_implicit(Eq(x**2+y**2,1),title='with xlim and ylim\n',\
                   xlim=(-1,1), ylim=(-1,1),aspect_ratio='equal')

p2 = plot_implicit(Eq(x**2+y**2,1),title='with x_var and y_var\n',\
                   x_var=(x,-a*scal,a*scal), y_var=(y,-a,a))
```

(My Sympy-version: 1.1.1)