# Sympy: Set aspect ratio

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I'm using Spyder's Ipython console to try to get some quick parametric plots of functions.  For now I'm focusing on x = cos(t), y = sin(t).  I ran the command

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_session()
p = plotting.plot_parametric(cos(t),sin(t),(t,0,2*pi))
```

and I get an oblong plot of the curve.

If I enter

```
p.aspect_ratio = (1,1)
p.show()
```

nothing changes.  I try other aspect ratios and still nothing changes.

After looking at this answer [In sympy plotting, how can I get a plot with a fixed aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505768/in-sympy-plotting-how-can-i-get-a-plot-with-a-fixed-aspect-ratio)

I tried following their instructions to try to leverage matplotlib and I get no errors.  But when I enter

```
plt.show()
```

nothing shows.

Comment: In the current sympy version you can use `plot_parametric(cos(t), sin(t), (t, 0, 2 * pi), aspect_ratio=(1, 1))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `fig.show()` to display the graph. The following example produces a graph with equal aspect ratio:

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_session()
p = plotting.plot_parametric(cos(t),sin(t),(t,0,2*pi))
fig = p._backend.fig
ax = p._backend.ax
ax.set_aspect('equal')
fig.show()
```

h/t to [Sympy and plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747474/sympy-and-plotting)

Comment: The corresponding Sympy issue is https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11764 .

Answer (score 2):

This works also

```
from sympy import*
t=symbols('t')
p = plot_parametric(cos(t),sin(t),show=False)
p.aspect_ratio=(1,1)
p.show()
```

Comment: It's generally considered a bad idea to use `from X import *`, because you're potentially importing a lot more symbols than you might expect. Best practice is to use either `import X` and then qualify the names when you use them, like `X.some_function()`, or else use `from X import some_function`.